# C# function for moving to specific line in a WebBrowser form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on an application to test Web Service requests. The people who would be using this application have asked to be able to view the Raw XML of the requests/responses from the Web Service, and to do so I am using a WebBrowser and simply pointing it to a file that stores a running record of all the XML requests/responses. This allows the window to collapse and expand XML elements, and offers native color coding.

My issue is that I want to be able to jump to a specific line, or specific XML entry in the browser view. So far I have not been able to find anything that allows line navigation in this form. I thought that maybe I could just implement a search function that just searches for the entry in the WebBrowser, but it doesn't look like searching is supported either. Is there a method that allows similar functionality to what I want? Or is there a way to work around this?

--EDIT--

I have added some sample code of what I tried from the solution below. Below is a sample of the XML I want to parse, followed by my implementation of the suggested solution. I am searching for the "SAMP_DriverDetail_07-08-2019_T_14-51-19" entry.

```html
<ResponseHistory>
<SAMP_DriverList_07-08-2019_T_14-51-19>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" /> 
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <m:SAMP_DriverListResponse xmlns:m="sample.com">
  <Drivers xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Drivers> 
  <Scroll xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Scroll> 
     <SAMPURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://BLAHBLAH</SAMPURL> 
     <DrvList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="sam:PDRV_Struct[]" xmlns:sam="sample.com" /> 
    </m:SAMP_DriverListResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
</SAMP_DriverList_07-08-2019_T_14-51-19>

<SAMP_DriverDetail_07-08-2019_T_14-51-19>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" /> 
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:q1:SAMP_DriverDetail</faultcode> 
  <faultstring>Method not available</faultstring> 
 </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
</SAMP_DriverDetail_07-08-2019_T_14-51-19>
</ResponseHistory>
```

```
private void Jump(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JumpToElement("SAMP_DriverDetail_07-08-2019_T_14-51-19");
    }

private void JumpToElement(string tag)
    {
        var element = XmlView.Document.GetElementsByTagName(tag).OfType<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (element != null)
        {
            XmlView.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, element.OffsetRectangle.Top);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196163/discussion-on-question-by-nick-heisler-c-function-for-moving-to-specific-line-i).